# How to make a better TimePicker using two NumberPickers (Hour value increments/decrements as Minute value crosses 59/0)?

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-timepicker

While making an app that works as a countdown timer, I needed to make a dialog to set the amount of time to count down from. When I tried to use a TimePicker, I realized that I won't be able to use it in the way I intended to, that is, to select number of hours as the cap is at 24 hours. Also, I wouldn't be able to set the number of seconds.

So, I had to implement my own TimePicker using 2 NumberPickers. (I didn't include the seconds NumberPicker yet)

I wanted to add a tiny functionality given by the TimePicker, where, if I were to roll the minutes selector past the value 59 to the value 00, it would increment the hours value by 1 (and similarly decrement it if I were to go from 00 to 59).

**Example:**

[image: Example]

I have used the following code to achieve my purpose, but a small problem remains.

**Java Code:**

```
final NumberPicker hr_np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.hr_timepicker);
final NumberPicker min_np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.min_timepicker);     
min_np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            if(newVal==0 && oldVal==59 && hr_np.getValue()<10)
                hr_np.setValue(hr_np.getValue()+1);
            else if(newVal==59 && oldVal==0 && hr_np.getValue()>0)
                hr_np.setValue(hr_np.getValue()-1);
        }
    });
```

**XML Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <NumberPicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hr_timepicker" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
        <NumberPicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/min_timepicker" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when I click on the NumberPicker value and type a new value directly, the above logic still sticks. Say, the current time is 03:59, I click the minute tab and type 00, the time changes to 04:00. This also occurs in the normal TimePicker.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use timepicker

```
<TimePicker
      android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: TimePicker won't let me select an interval of 50 hours. Also, as I already mentioned, TimePicker has the same problem that I'm facing.